# Start next Thread before previous finishes its work

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

My Code:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour()
{
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ExampleThread(), 1L, 1L, SECONDS);
}

private static class ExampleThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("2:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Example of the result will be:

```
1:1416599026988

2:1416599031988

1:1416599032989

2:1416599037989 

1:1416599038990
```

I have got no idea, what should be changed in the code, so next ExampleThread will be started after 1 Second since start of the previous Thread and not since its finish.

Sleep thing is just an example to show my problem.

So the result i would like to see would be:

```
1:1416599026988

1:1416599027988

1:1416599028988

1:1416599029988

1:1416599030988

2:1416599030988

1:1416599031988

2:1416599031988

1:1416599032988

2:1416599033988
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you please form this in more of a question of your problem?

Comment: How can i make next "ExampleThread" be started, before previous "ExampleThread" stops its work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with `ScheduledExecutorService`. The documentation for `scheduleWithFixedDelay` says:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently **with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next**. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor.

(My emphasis)

For `scheduleAtFixedRate`, the documentation says:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after `initialDelay` then `initialDelay+period`, then `initialDelay + 2 * period`, and so on. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. **If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute**.

This class was designed to **prevent** concurrent execution of its tasks.

You could, however, use the scheduler for threads whose only task is to run your ExampleThread:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour()
{
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ThreadMaker(), 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static class ThreadMaker implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread realThread = new Thread(new ExampleThread());
        realThread.start();
    }
}
private static class ExampleThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("2:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

In this manner, your scheduled task runs for only the split of a second it takes to create the new thread, so the scheduler will run about every second (if you use `scheduleAtFixedRate` it will be more exact). And the "real" threads are free to run concurrently. Of course, you'll have more than one `ExampleThread` object if you do it this way, and you'll also need to figure out how to communicate with the created threads to cancel them, as they are not available directly from the `ScheduledFuture` object returned by `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: I love your solution. Thanks a lot for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

ScheduledExecutorService are not aimed to run concurrent instance of the job, actually the next thread is not started before current one is finished. the method you use is just a convenient way to avoid rescheduling of the next job at the end of the current one.

You could use scheduler to schedule the next job as the first command of your run. like :

```
private static class ExampleThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        scheduler.schedule(new ExampleThread(), 0L, 1L);
        System.out.println("1:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you only start the first thread (either with new Thread or using an ExecutorService).
be sure to increase corePoolSize parameter in the factory of the ScheduledExecutorService to able other thread in the pool.

Another approach that I prefere, is to create a wrapper that only launch your job. then you schedule your wrapper :

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void beepForAnHour() {
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ExampleWrapperThread(), 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private class ExampleWrapperThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pool.execute(new ExampleThread());
    }
}

private int _examplethread_id = 0;
private class ExampleThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sid = _examplethread_id++;
        System.out.println(sid + ":" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(sid + ":" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```